# Configuring etc/hostname

Tags: dns, hostname

I just received my Raspberry Pi, and wanted to set up a small webserver.

I am not sure what to put as my hostname. I have bought a domain, for the sake of the question, let's assume it's `mydomain.com`.

I first tried setting the hostname to webserver, so that my fully qualified name would be webserver.mydomain.com. But I read that the hostname should be in DNS. So my second thought is to set this to mydomain. Am I correct in this assumption?

Comment: Please read our help pages so that you understand what this site is for and what it isn't for before posting again.

Comment: This question is better suited for the Super User network. Also, use `man hostname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're holding Raspberry Pi in your hands then you're lucky man.
If you've already registered you domain as mydomain.com, so there is no problem to set hostname as server.mydomain.com or webserver.mydomain.com. If your server will works directly with internet then you need to set WAN IP address on it and configure A record in your domain control panel, say:

```
webserver.mydomain.com  A XXX.XX.XXX.XX
```

If you will lease a private IP address then you need to look at [Dynamic DNS](http://www.gnutomorrow.com/best-free-dynamic-dns-services-in-2013/)

If you will use your webserver in private mode and want to ssh to it via FQDN then you need setup your [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file at your PC

Comment: but then I need to access the server via webserver.mydomain.com, right? Is there a way to do the same for just mydomain.com?

Comment: yes, just set A record.

Comment: I already have such a record, are then saying that without doing anything I can access webserver.mydomain.com from mydomain.com if I have the A record for mydomain set, and it points to webserver?

Comment: then you need two A records:
A         XXX.XX.XXX.XX    and      
webserver  XXX.XX.XXX.XX